# Legend combined with Text, how to find the legend width and height

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend, legend-properties

I would like to set legend and text boxes locations and styles exactly same, the latter especially to make text aligned.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
for i in range(3):
    ax.plot(x, i * x ** 2, label = '$y = %i x^2$'%i)
ax.set_title('example plot')

#  Shrink the axis by 20% to put legend and text at the bottom 
#+ of the figure
vspace = .2
box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0 + box.height * vspace, 
box.width, box.height * (1 - vspace)])

#  Put a legend to the bottom left of the current axis
x, y = 0, 0
#  First solution
leg = ax.legend(loc = 'lower left', bbox_to_anchor = (x, y), \
bbox_transform = plt.gcf().transFigure)

#  Second solution
#leg = ax.legend(loc = (x, y)) , bbox_transform = plt.gcf().transFigure)

#  getting the legend location and size properties using a code line I found
#+ somewhere in SoF
bb = leg.legendPatch.get_bbox().inverse_transformed(ax.transAxes)

ax.text(x + bb.width, y, 'some text', transform = plt.gcf().transFigure, \
bbox = dict(boxstyle = 'square', ec = (0, 0, 0), fc = (1, 1, 1)))
plt.show()
```

This should place the text at the right of the legend box but that's not what it does. And the two boxes are not vertically aligned.
The second solution does not actually anchoring the legend to the figure, but to the axes instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the frame data to get the right width in order to position the `Text()` object correctly.

In the example below I had to apply a `1.1` factor for the width (this value I haven't found how to get, and if you don't apply the factor the text clashes with the legend).

Note also that you must `plt.draw()` before getting the right width value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 2))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
for i in range(3):
    ax.plot(x, i*x**2, label=r'$y = %i \cdot x^2$'%i)
ax.set_title('example plot')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

x, y = 0.2, 0.5
leg = ax.legend(loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(x, y),
                bbox_transform=fig.transFigure, fontsize=8)
plt.draw()
f = leg.get_frame()
w0, h0 = f.get_width(), f.get_height()
inv = fig.transFigure.inverted()
w, h = inv.transform((w0, h0))

ax.text(x+w*1.1, y+h/2., 'some text', transform=fig.transFigure,
        bbox=dict(boxstyle='square', ec=(0, 0, 0), fc=(1, 1, 1)),
        fontsize=7)

fig.savefig('test.jpg', bbox_inches='tight')
```

for `x, y = 0.2, 0.5`:[image]

for `x, y = -0.3, -0.3`:

[image]

Comment: I'm not getting the same result. I'm using matplotlib 1.1.1; which one is yours? Could you put the values of f, w0, h0, inv, w, h? Also would you have the same result without using figsize = (3, 2)?

Comment: @user1850133 I am using matplotlib 1.3.1, let's continue this chat in [this room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52731/discussion-between-saullo-castro-and-tcapelle)